# cql3 query with more than 1 EQ restriction and ORDER BY

Tags: cassandra, cql3

using CF:

```
CREATE TABLE history (
  domain text,
  iid text,
  timeid timeuuid,
  data text,
  comments text,
  PRIMARY KEY (domain, iid, timeid)
);
```

I'd like to query it like this:

```
select domain, iid, timeid, data, comments from mappings
where domain = 'a' and iid = 'b'  order by timeid desc;
```

But it fails with the following error (cassandra 1.1.5):

```
Bad Request: Order by currently only support the ordering of columns following their declared order in the PRIMARY KEY
```

Am I doing it wrong? What could be the workaround?
Thx

PS I got it working with the single EQ restriction and ORDER BY but I need at least 2 restrictions and order by.

Comment: Is 'iid' an indexed column ?

Comment: I don't want to discourage you but according to:
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cql-3-0

"ORDER BY clauses can only select a single column, and that column has to be the second
 column in a composite PRIMARY KEY. This holds even for tables with more than 2 column
 components in the primary key. " Hopefully this will change soon. Is changing the CF an option?

Comment: @Istern as long as iid is part of primary key i expect it is indexed

Comment: @Oren it's funny as I read that but the devil in details.. thanks for pointing me there again! Yes I can change CF what would you advise?

Answer (score 9):

You can change 'order by' column to second column in primary key:

`select * from history where domain = 'a' and iid = 'b' order by iid desc;`

It is a bit confusing because you restrict `iid` with equality, but it works - you will get your result sorted by `timeid`.

I believe this is because `iid` and `timeid` form one composite column and when you order by `iid` in descending order, it orders all composite column components including `timeid`.

Comment: +1 to this answer for correctness, -1 to Cassandra for not supporting this simple feature in a simple way.

Comment: I believe it should be "order by iid, desc". a comma is missing.

Comment: see examples here - [link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/useColumnsSort.html) - no comma is necessary